# Completely remove AdView

Tags: android, admob

I have an `AdView` defined in my `Layout`'s XML and I want to make it disappear if the user bought the ad-free version of the app.

What I'm doing is

```
if(userhaspurchased){
    if (mAdView != null) {
        mAdView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mAdView.pause();
        ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) mAdView.getParent();
        mAdView.destroy();
        vg.removeView(mAdView);
        mAdView = null;
    }
    Log.d("Purchased","true");
} else { //Load ad }
```

And the ad is not visible, but in logs I'm still getting AdView messages:

```
02-25 11:14:58.688: I/Ads(9279): Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad.
02-25 11:14:58.688: I/Ads(9279): Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
```

And they are repeated every minute. Is there any way to disable completely the `AdView`?

**Update:** @Doomsknight answer is fine in my case, where I just have 2 layouts with ads. Otherwise would be a best practice to check the purchase and eventually insert the `AdView` programmatically.

Comment: Your xml is defining the ad view. And the connection automatically. You could have a paid version xml, and set that xml if paid at the top that doesnt define the adview at all

Comment: Wow, I didn't think to this solution!

Comment: It will be an overkill if you have to maintain two different xml layouts just for a single view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your xml is defining the ad view. And the connection automatically. So while you hide it, it has already been initialised.

One solution would be to have an xml that excludes the adview completely, for the paid version.

and set it at the top

```
if(userhaspurchased)
     setContentView(R.layout.paid_version_xml);
else
     setContentView(R.layout.free_version_xml);
```

This however depends on how many xmls you have, and adviews. As maintaining a variation for each page with adview on it may be an issue.

Comment: I have just 2 xml layouts with ads. So it's not a big deal. Thanks!

Comment: @Vektor88 Yea, i got that impression so posted an answer. Just put in the note, for others so they are aware of potential problems.

Answer (score 3):

Don't add the adview view in the xml file. Instead, add a placeholder in the xml layout file.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/admob"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

</LinearLayout>
```

In your code:

```
if(!userhasPurchased)
{
    AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, adunit_id);
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.admob);
    layout.addView(adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest); 
}
```

Comment: This is a better solution :) +1

Comment: When you've to deal with many Layouts that's fine. However if you want to use SMART_BANNER size, you'll have headaches if you try to insert it programmatically.